# How do I print Content stored in Object class?

Tags: java, object, collections

I am trying to store content in `Object` from context Object in case of `Servlet`.

like that

```
Object oList = scontext.getAttribute("LSList");
```

Now i want to print content stored in `Object` class, How I does this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try give more code to make us help you. And Maybe you need to have a look Reflection API

Comment: *"An attribute allows a servlet container to give the servlet additional information not already provided by this interface. See your **server documentation** for information about its attributes."*

Comment: There is no content in an `Object ` of any interest. Possibly you need to cast it to some class of more interest and call the methods of that class.